# AUTO_INCREMENT пропускает номера

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица с такой структурой:

> id - AUTO_INCREMENT
>
> name - varchar ( УНИКАЛЬНЫЙ )

Добавление новой записи в таблицу выполняется кодом:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`name`) values ($name)");
```

Если встречаются одинаковые значения **$name** - запись не добавляется, с этим порядок.

Но вот записи в таблице выглядят так:

> ID - name
>
> 1  - Igor
>
> 3  - Masha
>
> 6 -  Vita
>
> 7   Dima
>
> 10 - Viktor

То есть ID перескакивает почему-то... Как этого избежать?

Comment: Избежать - никак. Почему - ну, так есть (для обеспечения нумерации без необходимости блокировки таблицы). Оставить как есть и не обращать внимание

Comment: @Денис, [ваш случай](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql)

Comment: Так а если просто перед этим проверять наличие имени в бд и не давать команду INSERT?

Comment: @Dodik это уже дополнительный запрос к базе... нагрузка...

Comment: вам для эстетического удовольствия нужны номера по порядку что ли?

Comment: Не в тему: почему до сих пор mysql_?